# How to add asterisk and hyphen between two adjacent even and odd numbers within a string

Tags: c#

I have below code to accomplish this task but is their a way to refactor this code ?

```
        //input string
        string numbers = "12467930";
        string result = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {

            int value1 = (int)char.GetNumericValue(numbers[i]);
            int value2 = i + 1 < numbers.Length
                    ? (int)char.GetNumericValue(numbers[i + 1])
                    : 0;
            // To check odd numbers
            if (value1 % 2 != 0 && value2 % 2 != 0)
            {
                result += numbers[i] + "-";
            }
            // To check even numbers
            else if (value1 % 2 == 0 && value2 % 2 == 0)
            {
                // skipping 0 if present in the input string
                if (value1 != 0 || value2 != 0)
                    result += numbers[i] + "*";
                else
                    result += numbers[i];
            }
            else
            {
                //for even and odd combination number
                result += numbers[i];
            }
        }

        return result;
```

Comment: What is the actual question?  What specifically are you trying to address with a refactor?  If you have __specific goals for your refactor__, you can take your working code to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things I'd address:

1) If you loop to `numbers.Length - 1`, you can avoid checking if there's a value2.

2) You can do a single both-numbers-even-or-odd check if you use the result of the modulo operation as an index into an array of delimiters.

3) When doing a bunch of string concatenations, I always try to use a `StringBulder`.

```
string numbers = "12467930";
char[] delimiters = { '-', '*' };
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(numbers.Length * 2);

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length - 1; ++i)
{
    int value1 = (int)char.GetNumericValue(numbers[i]);
    int value2 = (int)char.GetNumericValue(numbers[i + 1]);
    int mod1 = value1 % 2;
    int mod2 = value2 % 2;

    if (value1 != 0 && mod1 == mod2)
        result.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", value1, delimiters[mod1]);
    else
        result.Append(value1);
}

result.Append(numbers.Last());
return result.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Refactoring** is the process of changing a software system in such a way that it does not alter the external behavior of the code yet improves its internal structure. (With that being said I'll change this how I would do it.)

```
    //input string
    string numbers = "12467930";
    string result = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        //This should keep it running one more time unnecessarily.
        if(i + 1 < numbers.Length){
             result += numbers[i];
             break;
        }else{
             int value2 = (int)char.GetNumericValue(numbers[i + 1]);
        }
        int value1 = (int)char.GetNumericValue(numbers[i]);
         //check if it's zero
         if(value1 != 0 || value2 !=0){
               //if they are both odd add a hyphen
               if (value1 % 2 != 0 && value2 % 2 != 0){
                     result += numbers[i] + "-";
               //otherwise if they are even and not zero add an asterisk
               }elseif (value1 % 2 == 0 && value2 % 2 == 0){
                     result += numbers[i] + "*";
               //if they are not both odd or even and not zero concatenate the number to the result.
               }else{
                     result += numbers[i];
               }
         //otherwise one number is zero
         }else{
               result += numbers[i];
         }
    }
    return result;
```

The ternary was nice but, it also allowed the code one final iteration so I changed that. I rearranged the if statements. That way it checks if it's a 0 first without needing to check the other conditions. This looks a lot like what you already had but, it will have improved execution.

Comment: I forgot a condition in the rewrite. If they are not both even or odd it needs to result += numbers[i];. Woops I will edit it.